# How to access secrets in databricks initscript

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, azure-secrets

I have tried to access the secret `{{secrets/secrectScope/Key}}` in advanced tab of databricks cluster and it is working fine. But when I try to use the same in databricks init script, it is not working it.

What are the steps to do that?

Comment: Please post sample code and describe the issue you're having (i.e error message). There is very little information in this question

Answer (score 5):

Another answer is correct regarding the syntax of the secrets reference (so-called "[secret paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secrets#--secret-paths-in-spark-configuration-properties-and-environment-variables)"), but it won't work for init scripts, although it will work for Spark code itself.

To pass the secret to the init script you need to put the secrets path into the ["Environment Variables" sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/configure#environment-variables) of the Spark configuration tab, like this:

[image]

And after that [you can use the variable by name inside the init script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secrets#store-the-path-to-a-secret-in-an-environment-variable):

```sh
if [ -n "$SECRET_VAR" ]; then
  do_something_with_it
fi
```

Comment: And how would you add the environment variable to every new cluster including job clusters? Would you do it via cluster policies `spark_env_vars.<environment variable name>`?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use cluster policies.

Comment: Do you have a pointer how I can set a secret path as an environment variable in a cluster policy? I couldn't find anything in the docs how to use secrets in cluster policies given the json syntax.

Comment: I think I solved it after some trial and error as so `"spark_env_vars.MYVAR": {
    "type": "fixed",
    "value": "{{secrets/my_scope/mysecret}}"
  },`

Answer (score 1):

**Here are the steps to access secrets in databricks initscript:**

1. Go to **cluster**
2. Click **Edit** next to the Cluster information.
3. On the Configure Cluster page, click **Advanced Options**.
4. On the **Spark** tab, enter the following Spark Config:

[image]

**Sample ini code:**

```
 fs.azure.account.auth.type.chepragen2.dfs.core.windows.net OAuth
 fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.chepragen2.dfs.core.windows.net org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider
 fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.chepragen2.dfs.core.windows.net {<!-- -->{secrets/KeyVaultName/ClientID}}
 fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.chepragen2.dfs.core.windows.net {<!-- -->{secrets/KeyVaultName/ClientSecret}}
 fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.chepragen2.dfs.core.windows.net https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Directory_ID>/oauth2/token
```

For more details, refer [Azure Databricks - configure the cluster to read secrets from the secret scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/tutorials/run-jobs-with-service-principals#--create-a-job-in-azure-databricks-and-configure-the-cluster-to-read-secrets-from-the-secret-scope).

Comment: you missed the `{{}}` around names, like this: `{{secrets/<secret-scope-name>/<secret-name>}}`